# Передача данные из компонента в компонент

Tags: vue.js

Как передат значения counter  в другой компонент после router.push?

Методы которые записаны в компоненте из которого нужно передать

```
incCounterBuy() {
    if (this.counterBuy > 0) {
        this.counterBuy--
   }
```

},decCounterBuy() {

this.counterBuy++
}

Пропс в этом же компоненте из которого нужно передать

```
 props: {
        isCounter: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
        }
    }
```

Значения counterBuy передать в другой компонент и отрендерить {{ counter }}

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Что то код по-моему код не полный. Где используется isCounter? Откуда берется counter? А вообще что бы передать значение в другой компонент удобнее всего через store(vuex). Или через $emit изменять значение в родительской компоненте, а оттуда уже спускать пропс в нужный компонент.

Comment: просто нужно передать значения counterBuy в другой компонент

Comment: Если компоненты по соседству (родитель один), то вешаете событие через $emit на родителя, меняете в родительском компоненте свойство и спускаете пропс в нужный компонент. А если не по соседству, то лучше использовать store, потому что можно замучаться передавать эти данные по ступенькам.

Comment: можете показать пример как это сделать? Зачем  мне испольщовать стор если я хочу просто counter передать с одного компонента в другой - с родителя в дочерний

Comment: Уточнение. Нужно передать из родительского в дочерний? Или из одного дочернего в другой дочерний одного родителя?

Comment: из родителя по дочерний, просто передать counter

Answer (score 0):

В родительском компоненте регистрируем свойство:

```
data: () => ({
  counter = 1,
})
```

Передаем пропс в дочерний компонент:

```
<дочерний-компонент :counter="counter"></дочерний-компонент>
```

В дочернем компоненте принимаем пропс:

```
props: ['counter']
```

Если нужно изменить данные из дочернего компонента создаем метод:

```
methodName(){
  this.$emit('increment')
}
```

Передаем событие родителю:

```
<дочерний-компонент @incremen="parentIncrement" :counter="counter"></дочерний-компонент>
```

У родителя создаем метод parentIncrement в котором меняем свойство this.counter. Все! Данные изменятся реактивно.

Comment: Возможно я не правильно выразился - как передать counter по клику в другом роут ?

Comment: Я бы использовал vuex. Про передачу props между роутами ничего сказать не могу. Сори!